# Disable Security and maintenance notifications using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, security, notifications

Is there a way to disable security notifications on windows 10 using powershell? 
I can disable through GUI but would be easier using a script.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Either use Group Policy or find the registry entries and use Powershell to change those entries: https://www.ghacks.net/2017/03/27/disable-security-messages-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

Modifying following Windows registry keys using ps could do the trick (For W10):

To disable security center notifications (non-critical ones):

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender Security Center\Notifications : DisableEnhancedNotifications
```

To disable ALL security center notifications :

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender Security Center\Notifications : DisableNotifications
```

To disable ALL notifications:

```
HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer : DisableNotificationCenter

HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications : ToastEnabled
```

Code should look like this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "$REG_LOCATION" -Name "$REG_KEY" -Type $TYPE -Value $VALUE

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender Security Center\Notifications" -Name "DisableEnhancedNotifications" -Type DWord -Value 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume this will disable all notifications? is there a way to disable specific notifications like only the network firewall notification?

Comment: Modified answer to include security center related registry keys.